# XPath query for a node

Tags: xml, xpath, libxml2

I should be doing something wrong. What is the XPath query for all nodes named "name" under display-name? I am using libxml2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<description xmlns="http://openoffice.org/extensions/description/2006" xmlns:d="http://openoffice.org/extensions/description/2006"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <version value="2010.05.25" />
    <identifier value="German.frami2006DE.dictionary.from.org.openoffice.de.by.Karl.Zeiler" />
    <display-name>
        <name lang="en">German (DE-frami) spelling, hyphenation, thesaurus</name>
        <name lang="de">Deutsche (DE-frami) Rechtschreibung, Trennung, Thesaurus</name>
    </display-name>
    <platform value="all" />
    <dependencies>
        <OpenOffice.org-minimal-version value="3.0" d:name="OpenOffice.org 3.0" />
    </dependencies>
</description>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your document has a default namespace, so you need to register that namespace in your expression. I've never used `libxml2`, but looking at their [examples](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/#xpath1.c), it would appear that the function you want is `xmlXPathRegisterNs`

Note that when you register a namespace, the prefix that you choose for your XPath expression doesn't have to match the prefix (if any) used in the document. Since you're document uses a default namespace (not prefix), it definitely won't. However, you still need to use a prefix in your XPath:

`/ns:description/ns:display-name/ns:name`

Answer (score 5):

Here is what worked:

```
xmlXPathRegisterNs(Ctxt, 'ns1', 'http://openoffice.org/extensions/description/2006');
Res := xmlXPathEval('//ns1:name', Ctxt);
```